# JS: Loop with multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, sorting, if-statement

I have an array of objects (cars), from which I want to show just the cars which "compete".

```
const cars = [
  {
    name: "red",
    competes: true,
    category: 1
  },
  {
   name: "blue",
   competes: false,
   category: 1
  },
  {
    name: "green",
    competes: true,
     category: 2
  },
  {
    name: "yellow",
    competes: true,
    category: 3
  }
]
```

But from those cars which compete, i only want to show those cars which are in category one, which is fine with a for loop.

The objects are now static but since i want to change them in a second moment, i need a code which checks if the cars compete and then checks if there are cars in "category" one.

- If there are cars in "category 1", list them
- If there are no cars in "category" 1, list those in "category" 2 (but not 3)
- And so on

*My try was with a loop inside a loop, bit that doesnt work since it displays all multiple times*

```
for (let i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
  if (cars[i].competes === false) continue;
  
  for (let f = 0; f < cars.length; f++) {
  if (cars[f].category > 1) break;
  console.log(`Cat1: ${cars[f].name}`);
}
}
```

**How can this be resolved if the "category" attributes inside "cars" are for example all 2 or more?**

```
const cars = [
  {
    name: "red",
    competes: true,
    category: 2
  },
  {
   name: "blue",
   competes: false,
   category: 2
  },
  {
    name: "green",
    competes: true,
     category: 3
  },
  {
    name: "yellow",
    competes: true,
    category: 4
  }
]
```

Comment: Maybe sort the data by `category` first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you sort the array based on the category and then filter out an array with cars that are gonna compete

```js
const cars = [
    {
        name: "red",
        competes: true,
        category: 1
    },
    {
        name: "blue",
        competes: false,
        category: 1
    },
    {
        name: "green",
        competes: true,
        category: 2
    },
    {
        name: "yellow",
        competes: true,
        category: 3
    }
]
const sorted = cars.sort((a, b) => a.category - b.category);
const compete = sorted.filter(x => x.competes && x.category == sorted[0].category);
console.log(compete[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution with sort and filter

```js
const cars = [
  {
    name: "red",
    competes: true,
    category: 1
  },
  {
   name: "blue",
   competes: false,
   category: 1
  },
  {
    name: "green",
    competes: true,
     category: 2
  },
  {
    name: "yellow",
    competes: true,
    category: 3
  }
]

let result = cars.sort((a,b) => a.category - b.category)
                 .filter(car => car.competes && (cars.length && car.category == cars[0].category))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Works great, thank You! If i log "result" it shows correctly. How could i just show the name of the resulting cars though?

Comment: you can loop through the result and show the name show the name where you need it

Answer (score 1):

We can start by getting the 'competing category' by getting the lowest competing category present, using `Math.min()` and Array.filter()

We can then get all competing cars by using `Array.filter()` to return only cars with a `competes` value that is truthy and also belongs to the competing category.

```js
    
const cars = [ { name: "red", competes: true, category: 1 }, { name: "blue", competes: false, category: 1 }, { name: "green", competes: true, category: 2 }, { name: "yellow", competes: true, category: 3 } ]

// Only this category is competing.. 
const competingCategory = Math.min(...cars.filter(car => car.competes).map(({category}) => category));
const competingCars = cars.filter(car => car.competes && car.category === competingCategory);

console.log('Competing cars:', competingCars)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

This example has only category 2 and 3 present:

```js
    
const cars = [ { name: "blue", competes: true, category: 2 }, { name: "green", competes: true, category: 2 }, { name: "yellow", competes: true, category: 3 } ]

// Only this category is competing.. 
const competingCategory = Math.min(...cars.filter(car => car.competes).map(({category}) => category));
const competingCars = cars.filter(car => car.competes && car.category === competingCategory);

console.log('Competing cars (example II):', competingCars)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```